# avahi : How to associate hostname with address of eth0:avahi generated by avahi-autoipd?

Tags: linux, networking, avahi

am using avahi on a freescale imx6 board with a custom linux system (build by buildroot).

So I use avahi for address allocation (eth0:avahi) and hostname resolution. My freescale imx6 board also uses an other interface with a "static" network address used in an other subnet mask (eth0).

I have also created an other interface eth0:0 with an other address (this third ethernet address is only created in order to understand my problem)

ifconfig of my freescale imx6 board :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1E:ED:19:27:1A:B3 
          inet addr:192.168.1.212  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3037485 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12312042 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:213265042 (203.3 MiB)  TX bytes:1150418317 (1.0 GiB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1E:ED:19:27:1A:B3 
          inet addr:134.124.45.23  Bcast:134.124.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1E:ED:19:27:1A:B3 
          inet addr:169.254.6.124  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:484 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:484 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:32284 (31.5 KiB)  TX bytes:32284 (31.5 KiB)
```

For my test, i use a pc connected with my freescale imx6 board. I launch command "avahi-browse -a -c -r -v " from this pc.

When I launch avahi-browes from my pc, I can see the hostname (name.local) of the freescale imx6 board but it is associated with the address of interface eth0:0 and not eth0:avahi. When i remove the interface eth0:0, the hostname of the freescale imx6 board is associated with eth0.

From my pc, I can ping freescale imx6 board using eth0, eth0:avahi address and eth0:0 (when it's activated)

My problem : I want, when i launch command "avahi-browse -a -c -r -v", my freescale imx6 board to return the address associated with eth0:avahi because, currently, my freescale imx6 board returns the last interface configurated (in my exemple, eth0:0) Do you know how to do that ?

Thank you for your answers,